# v-if not rendering when state changes in a method

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue for the first time and so for I'm satisfied with what it can do. I have a problem though, I have a method in my vue instance that does a query like so :

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        search: "",
        results: [],
        loading: false,
    },
    methods: {
        find: function(event) {
            this.loading = true;
            var siret = this.search.length > 9;
            var ep = this.$resource('/api/v1/.../{id}');
            ep.get({id: this.search, limit: 100}).then(function(response) {
                this.results = response.data;
            }, function(response) {
                // error handling
            });
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Now in my HTML I have something like this :

```html
<div v-show="loading" style="width:100%;" class="loader"></div>
```

Thing is, when I'm in the method, the state isn't instantly taken into account and is only rendered when exiting the method. What could I do so my loader appears as soon as this method is called and hidden when the method returns ?

To clarify what I meant :
If I modify the state of `loader` in the method to `true`, it displays the loader correctly. But if I modify it to `true` at the start of the method and set it back to `false` at the end of the method, I'd expect the loader to display for the time the method executes and then disapear. But it doesn't display at all. As if the state and the rendering was only rendered outside the method and not inside.

**EDIT**

I did not realize the ajax request was actually returning a promise, thus the method took only a few ms, not enough to see the loader. The problem was fixed by simply using `this.loading = false` inside the promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function in the success callback of your ajax request for `this` to represent the correct vue instance

```
ep.get({id: this.search, limit: 100}).then((response) => {
            this.results = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
            // error handling
        });
```

`this` inside your success callback is not pointing towards the vue instance that's why you cannot access the date of properties and mutate them.

Arrow functions bind the value of `this` lexically pointing the correct vue instance.

Or use the concept of closure by creating a `var self = this` inside your method and use `self`  inside the success callback

```
methods: {
    find: function(event) {
        var self = this;
        this.loading = true;
        var siret = this.search.length > 9;
        var ep = this.$resource('/api/v1/.../{id}');
        ep.get({id: this.search, limit: 100}).then(function(response) {
            self.results = response.data;
            self.loading = false;
        }, function(response) {
            // error handling
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `results` is updated just fine. It's just the loader that doesn't display until the method returns and that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @Depado what do you mean by method returns

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I meant

Comment: @Depado sry still not exactly sure what is wrong can you reproduce it in a fiddle

Comment: I think I solved it. The method is too quick for the effect to be visible, adding a wait step in the method actually shows the loader. I'll mark this as solved as soon as I can

Comment: @Depado great.. happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of the scope of `this`

Comment: Oh wait I understand what's going on. The ajax call returns a promise, that's why the method exits so quickly. So in fact your solution works ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Depado good you figured it out....have a nice day :)